# Blank Window JavaFX

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, scenebuilder

How do i fix this, a blank window opens on running the project

this is my main:

```
package application;

import java.io.IOException;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;


public class Main extends Application {

private Stage primaryStage;

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
    primaryStage.show();
}

public void mainWindow() {
    try {
        FXMLLoader loader =new FXMLLoader(Main.class.getResource("/MainWindowView.fxml"));
        AnchorPane pane = loader.load();
        MainWindowController mainWindowController = loader.getController();
        mainWindowController.setMain(this);
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
    }
}
```

this is my view xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="1080.0" prefWidth="1920.0" 
xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" 
fx:controller="application.MainWindowController">
<children>
  <Label fx:id="label" alignment="CENTER" layoutY="420.0" text="Label" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0">
     <font>
        <Font size="71.0" />
     </font>
  </Label>
  <HBox alignment="CENTER" layoutX="774.0" layoutY="540.0" spacing="20.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0">
     <children>
        <TextField layoutX="774.0" layoutY="540.0" />
        <Button layoutX="1268.0" layoutY="540.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleButton" text="Click Me!" />
    </children>
    </HBox>
</children>
</AnchorPane>
```

and this is my controller:

```
package application;

import java.awt.Label;
import java.awt.TextField;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;

public class MainWindowController {

    @FXML private Label label;
    @FXML private TextField field;


    private Main main;

    public void setMain(Main main) {

        this.main = main;

    }

    public void handleButton() {

        String text = field.getText();
        label.setText(text);

    }

}
```

this link has a link to all three of these codes in hastebin if want to be viewed that way(https://pastebin.com/raw/hbGBJUng), im new to java and javafx and am not sure what i am doing wrong as when i run the project in the eclipse it shows me an empty window as when i open the xml in scenebuilder, I have added a button, a label and a text field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You show just Stage without scene ,we can say null scene ,so if you need save your code i mean save your method main window ,just pass your stage as a parameter like this:

```
package application;

import java.io.IOException;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;


public class Main extends Application {

private Stage primaryStage;

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

mainWindow(primaryStage);  
}

public void mainWindow(Stage primaryStage) {
    try {
        FXMLLoader loader =new FXMLLoader(Main.class.getResource("/MainWindowView.fxml"));
        AnchorPane pane = loader.load();
        MainWindowController mainWindowController = loader.getController();
        mainWindowController.setMain(this);
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code in mainWindow should be in start, at the moment it is not ran, which causes only the start code to run, so nothing is staged and the empty stage is shown by show.